# how to change url of uiwebview when button is clicked?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview, interface-builder, iphone-sdk-4.1

hi i guess this is pretty simple and hope it will be answered in a easy manner!

how do i change the url of the uiwebview when a button is touched up inside?

meaning to say i will have a single web view and everytime a button is clicked the URL of the webview

changes and a new page is reloaded

thanks

Answer (score 4):

As you suggest, it's very easy:

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
  [webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://website.com/"]]];
}
```

This is all very [well documented](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: erm currently im am placing nsurl under view didload , will it still work - (void)viewDidLoad {
 [webWindow addSubview: activityIndicator];
 timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0) target:self selector:@selector(loading) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
 
 
 NSString *urlAddress = @"http://npshuttlebus.blogspot.com/2010/12/blog-post.html?m=1";
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
 NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 [webWindow loadRequest:requestObj];
 [super viewDidLoad];

Comment: You'll probably need to wait a bit after that. Try putting it in `viewWillAppear:`.